# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. Imposible traer la base de datos Firebase a la aplicación

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA PARA TRATAR DE AÑADIR MAS DATOS**

Tengo una App React Native que hace uso de Firebase.
Estoy tratando unir Firestore DataBase a mi aplicación, sin éxito.
Haciendo Debugger, compruebo que el arreglo me llega, gracias a un `console.log`, pero está vacío, y en la Base De Datos tengo varios elementos ingresados manualmente.
Muestro una imagen del `console.log`
La aplicación hasta ahora tiene una lista de productos que están en la base de datos, añadidos desde una aplicación Web, la cual está conectada perfectamente a Firebase DataBase. La base de datos esta conecta, como se puede ver en la captura del console.log, pero no trae los productos a la aplicación Móvil, deberían mostrarse en la interfaz de Usuario del Móvil los productos de la base de datos.

La App hasta ahora tiene un botón para para ver el menu que esta en Firestore Database.
No se que más puedo ofrecer para que puedan ayudarme, que archivos necesitarían. Muestro una captura de la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre recibo el mismo Warning :

```
>   @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.0): Could not reach Cloud
> Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This
> typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet
> connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode
> until it is able to successfully connect to the backend
```

He cambiado la versión de Firebase, he añadido código que a otros les funcionó, he buscado soluciones en GitHub, etc. También busque solución en este sitio, pero no consigo establecer conexión.

No puedo continuar con mi aplicación si no consigo traer los datos de la DataBase

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674482/firebase-firestore-firestore-5-0-4-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137494/react-native-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425061/firebase-firestore-not-connected-to-internet?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295674/firebase-firestore-and-authentication-errors

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081809/emulated-firstore-firestore-8-5-0-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend

Muestro alguno de los archivos que están relacionados con esta consulta a la DataBase.

Añado las dependencias:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.8",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Base De Datos de Firebase

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado el código que estoy utilizando

**Archivo firebase.js**

```js
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import firebaseConfig from './config'

class Firebase {
    /*constructor() {
        if(!app.apps.length) {
            app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
        }

        this.db = app.firestore()
    }*/

    constructor() {
        if (!app.apps.length) {
            
            app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
            
        }
        this.db = app.firestore()
    }
}

const firebase = new Firebase()
export default firebase
```

**Archivo firebaseState.js**

```js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

import firebase from '../../firebase'
import FirebaseReducer from './firebaseReducer'
import FirebaseContext from './firebaseContext'

import { OBTENER_PRODUCTOS_EXITO } from '../../types'

const FirebaseState = props => {

  // Crear state inicial
  const initialState = {
    menu: []
  }

  // useReducer con dispatch  para ejecutar las funciones
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FirebaseReducer, initialState)

  // Función que se ejecuta para traer los productos
  const obtenerProductos = () => {



    // consultar firebase
    //firebase.db.settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
    firebase.db
    //firebase.db.settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
      .collection('productos')
      .where('existencia', '==', true) // traer solo los que esten en existencia
      .onSnapshot(manejarSnapshot)
      
    function manejarSnapshot(snapshot) {
      let platos = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }
      })

      console.log(platos)
      // Tenemos resultados de la base de datos
      dispatch({
        type: OBTENER_PRODUCTOS_EXITO,
        payload: platos
      })    
    }
  }

  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider
      value={{
        menu: state.menu,
        firebase,
        obtenerProductos
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default FirebaseState
```

**Archivo Menu.js**

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import {  Text } from 'react-native'
import  FirebaseContext from '../context/firebase/firebaseContext'

const Menu = () => {

    // Context de Firebase 
    const { obtenerProductos} = useContext(FirebaseContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        obtenerProductos();
    }, [])

    return ( 
        <Text>Menu</Text>
     )
}
 
export default Menu
```

**Archivo NuevaOrden.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Button, Text } from 'native-base'
import globalStyles from '../styles/global'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const NuevaOrden = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation()

    return (
        <Container style={globalStyles.contenedor}>
            <View style={[globalStyles.contenido, styles.contenido]}>
                <Button
                    style={globalStyles.boton}
                    rounded
                    block
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Menu')}
                >
                    <Text style={globalStyles.botonTexto} >Crear Nueva Orden</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
        </Container>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contenido: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})

export default NuevaOrden
```

**Archivo firebaseContex.js**

```js
import { createContext } from 'react'

const FirebaseContext = createContext()

export default FirebaseContext
```

**Archivo. App.js**

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React from 'react'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import NuevaOrden from './views/NuevaOrden'
import Menu from './views/Menu'

// importar state de context
import FirebaseState from './context/firebase/firebaseState'
import PedidoState from './context/pedidos/pedidosState'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <FirebaseState>
        <PedidoState>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#FFDA00'
                },
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#000'
              }}
            >

              <Stack.Screen
                name="NuevaOrden"
                component={NuevaOrden}
                options={{
                  title: "Nueva Orden"
                }}
              />

              <Stack.Screen
                name="Menu"
                component={Menu}
                options={{
                  title: "Nuestro Menú"
                }}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </PedidoState>
      </FirebaseState>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hola, hay un issue levantado en el repo de firebase que tiene tu mismo problema, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7615#issuecomment-791627791 casi al final, uno de los devs de firebase comenta que no debes bloquear el hilo principal, y la persona con el problema logró solucionarlo al dejar de bloquear el hilo principal. Prueba sacando esta línea `firebase.db.settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })` o si hay alguna parte de tu código que esté bloqueando el main thread intenta retirarla

Comment: De esta pregunta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674482/firebase-firestore-firestore-5-0-4-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend) probaste todo verdad?

Comment: @AndresGardiol si he probado todo. Tambien quite la linea que comentas, y sigue sin traer los datos. La DB esta conectada, pero no trae los datos

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos la base de datos en cuestión?

Comment: En qué dispositivo estas teniendo el problema?

Comment: Por último, agrega qué versiones de dependencias estás usando. Acá encontré otro issue reportado y por esta parte empiezan a nombrar algunas soluciones posibles que podrías intentar: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2923#issuecomment-640737292

Comment: En casos como estos a veces conviene empezar todo de 0 en un proyecto nuevo y ver que pasa.

Comment: Podrías proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible de tu código? https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Para que podamos intentar reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo @AndresGardiol , he actualizado la pregunta y añadido más codigo, el que realmente es importante. El proyecto consta de 19 Archivos, sin contar los de Android e iOs

Comment: Agrega esta linea: `firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true});`

Answer (score 2):

Hice una respuesta de como integrar firebase con react de forma sencilla, aqui puedes verla

[firebase en react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485891/como-integrar-y-usar-el-firestorage-en-firebase-9-en-javascript-si-es-en-react/485921#485921)

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo solucione eliminando el proyecto y comenzando de nuevo