# como integrar y usar el firestorage en firebase 9 en javascript (si es en react mejor)

Tags: firebase

el problema es el siguiente hace un poca semana firebase actualizo la forma de interactuar con la api tanto como en firestore como en fireStorage el problema es que mientras que en la documentación oficial de configuración muestra como configurar el proyecto para la la nueva interfaz.

la firestorage todavía tiene la vieja documentación de la 8 que genera problema de importación y reconocimiento de dependencia un mensaje de ejemplo.

el método antiguo

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

> ./src/firebase/firebase.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'D:\portafolio\wolfw\wolfy-global\src\firebase'

el método nuevo

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

el firestore ya la librería da soporte pero tengo dudas es con el filestrorage

¿Cómo puedo use el filestorage en firebase 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Debes importar firabase completo y luego puedes acceder a todas sus funciones
siempre creo un archivo js con la coneccion

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
var firebaseConfig = {};
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxx" 
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

Después en cualquier lugar llamas este archivo

```
import firebase from "../../firebase";
```

y utilizas lo que necesites

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const storage=firabase.storage();
```

Ejemplo en una función

```
const addFile=(file)=>{
    const storageRef = storage.ref(`pictures/${file.name}`)
    const task = storageRef.put(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la versión 9 debes usar, por ejemplo:

```
import { getStorage, ref as sRef } from 'firebase/storage';
```

- **getStorage** -> Para obtener ficheros almacenados
- **ref** -> Que hay renombrar a sRef, por ejemplo, para no colisionar con otra 'ref' que usemos para la base de datos

El resto de métodos que podemos usar lo puedes ver en el paquete dentro de **firebase/storage** en la carpeta node_modules